# Advanced Organization of my database, need tips

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

**Original post is mostly solved, check Edit #2 for my most recent questions**

I hope it's easy for you guys to understand what i'm trying to do. I'm working on a project with cakePHP where it will allow users to log there drug use. Be it alcohol, caffeine, or whatever else. When people add a log, they select the substance from a drop down, they then enter the amount they took, and then type in the unit they choose to use for the measurement.

For example someone can choose Alcohol from the drop down, then enter in 12 for the dose, and then mL for the unit.

I've been working on ways to refine the way my data is structure so that when I have many entrys, it's easy to mold them to what I need them for. I will be using the data to generate graphs and charts for the users but that is unreleated.

I need help with figuring out the best way to organize this data

My current structure is like this.

My tables

```
drugs
id | drug
1  |  Alcohol

records
id | dose | unit | user_id
2  |  12  |  mL  |   3 

record_drugs
id | record_id | drug_id
4  |     2     |    1
```

I have these tables associates. So **drugs** is a list of all the available drugs provided in the drop down, the **records** table is where they can store the dose and unit and some other misc stuff, and the **record_drugs** basically pairs the record with the drug.

Some problems I have:

**1**. Lets say a use has multiple records for alcohol, I made a small script that adds all there alcohol doses, and then displays to them the total amount of alcohol they've recorded. If I do a simple find(list) I can get the drug name, and the total amount of dose, but then I can't get the unit associated with the drug. Because it seems like a foreach statement only supports passing two variables.

**EDIT: MORE INFO**
My find is pretty complex looking but what it does is go through my three tables listed above and grabs 3 fields. It is displayed like this in an array

```
array(
'mL' => array(
    'Alcohol' => '12'
),
```

Then, in my view I try to loop these results in a foreach to display my data like this.

```
Alcohol: 12 ml
```

I know how to format it and echo the variables I just don't know how to grab the three values in the array I need, and then put them into the echo.

**2**. What if i'd like to pair up many similar type of drugs. For example if I added Beer, Whiskey, Rum to the list. All of these are in the same 'category' and I would like to use these categories for certain features.

---

A solution i've been thinking of would be to also make the units part of another dropdown menu. And then only have one unit associated with the drug. So i'd probably change my drugs table to

```
drugs
id | drug | unit
1  |Alcohol| mL
```

But then, that leaves no room for customization for the user setting the unit. Maybe he want's to measure in beers, maybe he wants to measure in shots.

---

**Edit #2**

---

I've been working on normalizing my database here's the resulting layout

```
records
id | date | title | user_id
1  | Jan  | Title | 1

units
id | unit
1  | mL
2  | l

drugs
id | drug
1  | Alcohol

record_drugs
record_id | drug_id | unit_id | dose
1         | 1       | 2       | 5

//There is a users table, but it is unrelated, and correctly formatted.
```

Few questions;

1. For the first three tables above, for the id field. Should I name it "tablename_id" or just "id"?
2. The 'title' field will be a title that the user can choose to enter if they'd like to title there entry. Is it in the correct form?
3. How does a unit relative value work?

**I appreciate anyone taking the time to read this. I, of course, do not expect to have an entire solution to my problem just handed to me. But even if you could provide a tip or opinion on just one part of my problem, that will help me greatly.**

Comment: I'd suggest you normalize a bit more to abstract units into their own table. This way you can store unit amounts (relative to a base unit) and perform conversions on the fly. Something like `Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, UnitName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UnitRelativeValue DECIMAL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Id), UNIQUE KEY(UnitName)`

Comment: Also, I'm confused by `record_drugs`. Why does a record have multiple drugs? Does one 12 mL record with multiple drugs mean 12 mL of each? I think it would be more logical to make records to drugs one-to-many with a foreign key to drug in record.

Comment: From what I know about associations, I thought the hasMany Through was the correct method. A use can have the same drug once, or multiple times a day. A drug can be used by one user, or multiple users. I am not too experience, what do you mean by normalizing my abstract units into there own tables?

Comment: I included a bit more about normalizing your schema (fancy word for database) in my answer and I'll link to some good reading. The relationships I see here are a user has many records, and each record has one drug, one amount, and one unit.

Comment: Hello again. Your comment has been incredibly helpful and i've been spending a day learning about normalization. I updated the OP with another question, if you have any time for it. But still, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your first question, it is true that `foreach` only iterates over a key and an associated value in an associative array, but this can be expanded to iterate over a query result. Given that a query returns an array of columns and values, you can iterate over it with `foreach` and then access each column name from the column array.

```
$resultFromQuery = array(
    array(
        'columnOne' => 'valueOne',
        'columnTwo' => 'valueTwo'
    ),
    array(
        'columnOne' => 'valueThree',
        'columnTwo' => 'valueFour'
    )
);
```

Then when you iterate over it:

```
foreach($resultFromQuery as $result) {
    echo "From this result...\n";
    echo "columnOne: " . $result['columnOne'] . "\n";
    echo "columnTwo: " . $result['columnTwo'] . "\n";
}
```

---

Your second question depends entirely on what sort of functions these categories would need. You could create a table for categories and store a one-to-one foreign key for the category of each drug:

```
Categories
----------
id INT (primary)  <------+
name VARCHAR(255)        |
                         |
Drugs                    |
-----                    |
id INT (primary)         |
name VARCHAR(255)        |
category_id INT (fk) ----+
```

---

Also, I'd suggest you normalize a bit more to abstract units into their own table. This way you can store unit amounts (relative to a base unit) and perform conversions on the fly.

```
units
---------
Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT (primary index)
UnitName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL (unique index)
UnitRelativeValue DECIMAL NOT NULL
```

Given this structure, units also have an id, so you can store the user's preferred unit for each drug.

```
UserDefaultDrugUnit
---------------------
id (primary key)
user_id (foreign key)
drug_id (foreign key)
unit_id (foreign key)
```

This schema also allows for a fallback to a system default for each drug in a table named `DefaultDrugUnit` with a similar structure.

---

**EDIT** (in response to your edit of question 1)

To iterate through multi-dimensional arrays, you need to use nested `foreach` loops:

```
$units = array(
    'mL' => array(
        'Alcohol' => '12'
    )
);

foreach($units as $unit => $drugs) {
    foreach($drugs as $drug => $amount) {
        echo $drug . ' ' . $amount . ' ' . $unit . "\n";
    }
}
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/RzxdMs37))

Although, I'm not sure I follow the logic in this hierarchy. To me, something like this would make more sense:

```
array(
   'Alcohol' => array(
       'amount' => 12,
       'unit' => array(
           'name' => 'mL',
           'relativeQuantity' => 0.001 // ml in L
       )
   )
)
```

---

## Good Reading

- [How do you teach database normalization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820015/how-do-you-teach-database-normalization)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. The methods and things you said are a little above what I know for php/cakephp, but it's really great. I'm going to go through every point you said tomorrow and try and figure out what you mean and how to actually execute it the right way. It's going to be some very interesting and helpful stuff to learn. And I will reply after I start executing it to keep this updated. I realized I didn't explain my first question correctly. I'm updating my original post with what I meant if you can please check that out too